# Synchronizing COM Threads with .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, com

In our C# application we are making use of a thirdparty ([Thesycon](http://www.thesycon.com/eng/home.shtml)) COM object which runs threads to write data to a scanning device from 7 files.

I start the writing method by calling

```
COM.StartWriting()
```

and I can stop it by calling

```
COM.StopWriting()
```

Now the problem is I'm unable to synchronize the threads. This means out of 7 I always miss 4 files. 
If look in the Debug window, the worker thread type is shown as 'BackGround' and MTA.
How do I synch my Main and Worker threads?

Comment: You need to post a lot more information about the methods, properties and events available on the COM object you are using. And what do you mean by unable - are you able to modify the source of the COM object but you don't know how? Or is it a 3rd party component? And explain the sequence of events more carefully. Which code creates the files and gives them names, and how are they written to, read from, etc, and how are they "missed"?

Answer (score 0):

If the COM object provides no means to monitor its process, then the answer is going to be NO.

If the COM object does provide a mechanism, then you need to use that to determine when you can perform the `StopWriting`.